# Choropleth in Leaflet ajax

Tags: leaflet, geojson, topojson

I followed this tutorial here http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html  to make a State level choropleth using GEOJSON format of state.

Leaflet GeoJSON allows us to send AJAX request to get external parameters . Something like this

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'atl_metro.geojson',
    success: function(data) {
        $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {

            var zips = L.geoJson(data,{
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature, 
                style: style
            }).addTo(map);  

        });
    }
}).error(function() {});
```

Is there a way use it using TopJSON?

Comment: You've edited your question in such a way that my answer makes completely no sense anymore. :D You're misinterpreting a lot of things, i wouldn't know where to start. I'll answer your other question first maybe things will become clearer for you.

Comment: I am sorry, I will revert the edit so your answer makes sense again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use plain vanilla TopoJSON and throw out the omnivore plugin. It's just a wrapper and yet another dependency that you don't need because TopoJSON itself is very simple to use.

```
var url = 'https://rawgit.com/mbostock/topojson/master/examples/us-10m.json';

// Fetch topojson file via jQuery
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  // Convert the topojson to geojson 
  var geojsonData = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.counties);
  // Create new geojsonlayer with the data
  var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(geojsonData, {
    style: getStyle,
  }).addTo(map);
});

function getStyle(feature) {
  return {
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    color: '#fff',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    // fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density)
    // TopoJSON used in this example doesn't have any data attributes
    // so throwing in some random colors
    fillColor: '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
  };
}
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5Kn94H?p=preview

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question and formulate your question(s) in a better. I'm unsure to what you really are trying to accomplish. These are extra questions and that's cleary not what comments are meant for.

Comment: You're completely mistaken. You CANNOT use TopoJSON or GeoJSON to make AJAX/XHR requests. The `$.ajax` and the `$.getJSON` methods are coming from the jQuery library, which you are obviously using. The mouseevents have got nothing to do with Topo or GeoJSON either. The events are part of Leaflet. Doesn't matter if you use TopoJSON, convert it to GeoJSON, or use plain vanilla GeoJSON, once you load the GeoJSON data into Leaflet's GeoJSON layer, the layer is responsible for the events.

Comment: Yes thank you I have figured out this problem. I have implemented and got working the zoom and other functionalities as well!

The only thing left is that does topojson.featuure preserve properties of TopoJson file while converting to Geojson? I have already commented this in other question.  Thank for all your help!